# Is every vector space $V$ of countable dimension isomorphic to $V\oplus V$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

The problem:

> Let $V$ be a vector space of countable dimension over the field $K$. Show that, as $K$-vector spaces, $V$ is isomorphic to $V\oplus V$.

Please help.

Comment: this problem is quoted from a exercise of P.J.Hilton, U.Stammbach "A course in homological algebra" and "countable" may contain finite dimension case

Answer (score 2):

Assume you have a (countable) basis for $V$. Find a basis for $V\oplus V$. Find a bijection between the basis of $V$ and that of $V\oplus V$. Extend to a vector space isomorphism by linearity.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** $\aleph_0+\aleph_0=\aleph_0$. Remember that any function defined on the basis extends uniquely to a linear operator, and inherits injectivity.